# Response result from RapidAPI gives Relaxed JSON

Tags: java, json

[image]I got this response from RapidAPI, As you see in the picture the name indicated by the red vector
is without quotes. I searched for that and I found that is called Relaxed JSON, but I didn't find how to parse this type using Java language.

[image]

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 1):

This works for me

```
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonFactory;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParser;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode;
import com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.ObjectMapper;

String text = "{\n" +
        "  \"array\": [\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      0: {\n" +
        "        \"id\": 1\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    },\n" +
        "    {\n" +
        "      1: {\n" +
        "        \"id\": 2\n" +
        "      }\n" +
        "    }\n" +
        "  ]\n" +
        "}";

JsonParser parser = new JsonFactory()
        .createParser(text)
        .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_UNQUOTED_FIELD_NAMES)
        .enable(JsonParser.Feature.ALLOW_SINGLE_QUOTES);

JsonNode root = new ObjectMapper().readTree(parser);

System.out.println(root);
```

Result

```
{"array":[{"0":{"id":1}},{"1":{"id":2}}]}
```

Comment: how to parse that with Okhttpclient and  Request?

Answer (score 0):

It's nothing but that `0` is indicating the first value inside the `quotes` array. `Quotes` is an array with the 7 objects values. You can access them or get each value from an array using the [org.json](https://github.com/stleary/JSON-java) library.

```
import org.json.*;

JSONArray arr = obj.getJSONArray("quotes");
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length(); i++)
{
    String exchange = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("exchange");
    String shortname = arr.getJSONObject(i).getString("shortname");
    .
    .
    .
    // And so on...
}
```

Comment: hey and thanks for replying,the problem is when i want to call the "exchange" of the first item (0) only the code above call all the  other "exchange" items(1,2,3,4,5,6) of the "quotes".

Comment: I updated the picture